# explain recursion syntax

Tags: shell-script, recursive

I'm new to shell, and UNIX / GNU/Linux.

I'm trying to understand this syntax that is part of a recursion function:

```
 [ $i -le 2 ] && echo $i || { f=$(( i - 1)); f=$(factorial $f); f=$(( f * i )); echo $f; }
```

(taken from [here](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Recursive_function))

the full related function is:

```
factorial(){
  local i=$1
  local f
  declare -i i
  declare -i f
  [ $i -le 2 ] && echo $i || { f=$(( i - 1)); f=$(factorial $f); f=$(( f * i )); echo $f; }
```

}

I understand `[$i -le 2 ]` means check if there are at-least 2 positional arguments, I just don't understand what is the double pipe symbol (or?). Also what do the `{}` do? are they kind of a 4 arguments for loop?

Thanks,
David

Comment: ` [$i -le 2 ]` checks if $i (which is a copy of $1) is less than or equal to 2

Comment: For yr future enjoyment, another way of getting at most of @tomas' detailed break-up is : `man bash`. While visualizing the man page, hit "/" followed by any keyword: e.g. `/local` or `/declare` followed by several hits on the "n" key to get to the next occurence of the keyword. --- The recursion per se is C/C++ style stuff you might already be familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,

```
local i=$1
```

assigns the value of $1 to i. $1 is the first argument of the function. Or outside of a function, it stands for the first positional parameter of a command or script.

The following are quite intuitive. -i means the variable is an integer.

```
  local f
  declare -i i
  declare -i f
```

Now to the long one. I'll break it down into separate lines for clarity.

```
[ $i -le 2 ]    #checks if $i is less or equal 2

&&    #this is logical AND. This is used so: X && Y, meaning if X computes to true, then compute Y. So for this function, the meaning is: if $i less or equals 2, do the following:

echo $i     #this follows the logical && above, so is computed conditionally. Namely, print $i.

||    #this is logical OR, so what follows is computed only if what's on the left boils down to false.
      #Here the meaning is, IF NOT $i -le 2 AND echo... (which doesn't matter), do what's on the right. So do what's in the {} braces, if $i is greater than 2.
```

And now this is left:

```
 { f=$(( i - 1)); f=$(factorial $f); f=$(( f * i )); echo $f; }
```

The braces {} make what's in them a block, which is treated as an entity. To explain it appearing here most simply, the logic introduced before with && and || now applies to the whole block. Now to the parts.

```
f=$(( i - 1));
```

$(( )) is an arithmetic operator. f= you should know by now. The whole expression means assign to `f` the value of `i - 1`.

Notice how the parts of a block are ended with a semicolon `;`.

```
f=$(factorial $f);
```

The above calls the function. This is the place of recursion. Literal meaning: assign to `f` the return value of the function factorial called with the `$f` as an argument. (Assignment doesn't require the $, as you may have noticed.) The `$( )` is a *command substitution*. You can call a function by simply calling its name, but for a variable value assignment, the value has to be passed somehow, and that's how it's done here.

```
f=$(( f * i ));
```

Above you see the arithmetical operator again, ie `$(( ))`. `f` gets here the value of `f`, which by now is equal to `$(factorial $f)`, multiplied by `i`, which is equal to the $1 argument of the function.

And finally, print the value of `f`:

```
echo $f;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
||
```

logical OR

```
{}
```

begin-end of a function or set of commands

```
for
```

3 arguments: initialization, condition, iterator change

```
{ f=$(( i - 1)); f=$(factorial $f); f=$(( f * i )); echo $f; }
```

inline function giving back a number